# possibility of call native methods in .so file on Windows

Tags: java, android, linux, native

I only have android sdk(java library to call natively) and .so file which has native methods where java program can call to it.

So is there any possibility that I can do a java swing application to call that native methods in .so file on windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

No. An .so file is a Linux shared library, it cannot be used on Windows.

Comment: do you know any way to convert .so into .dll

Comment: No, there is no such way.